# Html.BeginForm with dynamic routevalues

Tags: ajax, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-routing, html.beginform, routevalues

I need to add a dynamic routevalue in html.beginform, something like this

```
Html.BeginForm("action", "controller", new { 

   somethingID = "some js function or jquery that get the value from a textbox" 

}))
```

I know mvc is already passing the paramenter to my method when the form submit, but I need the url to include the parameter in the mvc url format, ie `mydomain.com/controller/action/somethingID`. Eveything is working right now, but because I have another `$.ajax()` call that pass in the url, something like `"../someMethod"`, the `$.ajax()` dont work because the current url is `(mydomain.com/controller/action)` not `(mydomain.com/controller/action/somethingID)`.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure to set as `UrlParameter.Optional` the `id` in your RouteConfig:

```
routes.MapRoute(
       name: "Default",
       url: "{controller}/{action}/{id}",
       defaults: new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional}
);
```